# Adding space to begin of xAxis ticks in chartJS

Tags: reactjs, formatting, chart.js

I want to make bar chart xAxis ticks had space from yAxis gridlines,

i implement chartjs bar chart on reactjs, this is my progress

[image]

this code which i tried

```
          {
            paddingLeft: 10,
            type: "time",
            time: {
              unit: "day",
              unitStepSize: 10,
              displayFormats: {
                day: "YYYY-MM-DD"
              },
              max: lastDay
            }
          }
        ]
```

i expect implementing like canvasJS
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in options that will do the job.

`scales: {
    yAxes: [{ ticks: { callback: function(value, index, values) { return  value + ' '; } } 
}`

Comment: do you mean on xAxes?

Comment: the one you have mentioned is yAxes. I have tested the above its working fine. You will get your required space.

Comment: it pushed scale of yAxes more to left, but gridlines still on same position like on pictures

Comment: If you want to hide grideline extending beyond chart then you an use this. Else their is no other way to decrease that. `xAxes: [{
         gridLines: {
        drawTicks: false
      }
      }]` same for yAxes too.

Comment: but in this codepen it is expand from first gridLines O.o https://codepen.io/adrianhurt/pen/GqvBzo?editors=0010 @somsgod